# The cartesian product of a well-ordered set with $[0,1)$ is a linear continuum in dict. order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, real-numbers, well-orders

> **Definition**: A linear continuum is a simply ordered set $L$ such that:
>
> (1): $L$ has the least upper bound property;
>
> (2): For every $x<y$ in $L$ there is a $z$ sucht that $x<z<y$.

I need to show that, if $X$ is a well-ordered set (simply ordered with all subsets having a least element), then $X\times[0,1)$ is a linear contiuum.

With (2) I have no problem. For (1):

> Let $A\subset X\times[0,1)$ and $b = \inf\pi_1(A)$ ($\pi_1$ is the projection on the first coordinate). This infimum exists because $X$ is well-ordered then $\pi_1(A)\subset X$ has a least element. Then we prove that $\inf A = (b,0)$. Given $(x,y)\in A$, then $x\in\pi_1(A)$ hence $b\le x$. If $b<x$, then $(b,0)<(x,y)$. If $b=x$, once $0\le y$, either $(b,0) = (x,y)$ or $(b,0) < (x,y)$. If $(b,0) < (b',c)$ for some $b'\in X,c\in [0,1)$, then if $b<b'$ or $b'=b$ and $0<c$. If $b<b'$, because $b\in\pi_1(A)$, any element $(b,y)\in A$ is such that $(b,y) < (b',c)$(such an element exists in $A$ because $b\in\pi_1(A)$). If $b'=b$ and $c>0$...

If my reasoning above is right I just need to show for the last missing case, but I don't know how to prove the existance of an element $d$ of $\pi_2(A)$ lesser than $c$ such that $(b,c)\in A$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you looking for infima? You're trying to prove the least **upper** bound property...

Comment: Because I think that the greatest lower bound property will imply the least upper bound property.

Comment: Yes, but that just requires more proof...

Comment: I think you also used this statement to say that $X$ has the LUB property. The well-ordering of $X$ just implies the GLB property, isn't it? I was thinking in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to utilize the fact that $X$ is a well-order, but your reasoning is false. Suppose that $A=\{x\}\times(1/3,1/2)$, then how is $(x,0)$ going to be $\inf A$? It's clearly $(x,1/2)$. Even if you meant to prove that $(b,0)$ is the least upper bound, this is still wrong here.

Instead, note that $X$ also satisfies the least upper bound property. Every bounded set has a least upper bound. If $b=\sup\pi_1(A)$, then either $b\in\pi_1(A)$, in which our least upper bound is the appropriate $r\in[0,1)$ when taking the section at $b$; or $b\notin\pi_1(A)$, in which case, indeed $(b,0)$ is going to be the least upper bound.

Comment: Got it, thanks for you correction. But if the set was $X\times (0,1]$ then we would be forced to show the greatest lower bound property?

Comment: Well, if you want.